# Trying to combine VALUES and SELECT-FROM in one SQLite query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Here's little piece of pythonic sqlite query i wrote as self-teaching newbie:

```
cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO {mover_allocator[mover_targeter]}
              (ID, TITLE, SEASONS_WATCHED, PERSONAL_RATING, GENRE)
              VALUES
              (NULL, (SELECT TITLE FROM {selected_table} WHERE TITLE = '{title_to_move}'), ?, ?,
                     (SELECT GENRE FROM {selected_table} WHERE TITLE = '{title_to_move}'))""",
              (seasons_watched, series_rating))
series_database.commit()
```

And it works.
But i definitely dislike double SELECT-FROM in brackets, so i tried to rewrite it:

```
cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO {mover_allocator[mover_targeter]}
              (ID, TITLE, SEASONS_WATCHED, PERSONAL_RATING, GENRE)
              VALUES
              (NULL, TITLE, ?, ?, GENRE)
              SELECT TITLE, GENRE FROM {selected_table} WHERE TITLE = '{title_to_move}'""",
              (seasons_watched, series_rating))
series_database.commit()
```

And now it successfully doesn't.
Feeling a little tired already of documentation intricacies, i make wonder: is such approach possible at all? I mean, to combine VALUES and SELECT-FROM in one query sequentially?

update: in my case `{selected_table}` has only two columns instead of five in `{mover_allocator[mover_targeter]}`, columns mismatch in other words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this work by combining your `VALUES` into the `SELECT`, rather than the other way around:

```py
cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO {mover_allocator[mover_targeter]}
              (ID, TITLE, SEASONS_WATCHED, PERSONAL_RATING, GENRE)
              SELECT NULL, TITLE, ?, ?, GENRE FROM {selected_table} WHERE TITLE = ?""",
              (seasons_watched, series_rating, title_to_move))
```

Note that `title_to_move` should be a parameter as well.

Comment: In my case `{selected_table}` has only two columns instead of five in `{mover_allocator[mover_targeter]}`.
Columns mismatch, so SELECT cann't do its job this way. 
Though decision is interesting, noted it.
(and updated question, thnx)

Comment: @TahtunRazdronin the `SELECT` only attempts to read two columns from `{selected_table}`, `TITLE`, and `GENRE`. All the other values are constants

Comment: @TahtunRazdronin you might need to use something like a `CAST(? AS CHAR)` to make it work as a column definition. See for example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6wSp4K2N5gXAnM9SocWVTH/1

Comment: Forgot to commit(). 
Solution is quite working, 
Mea culpa.